# OCaml toplevel not interpreting comments

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-batteries

```
$ ocaml
        Objective Caml version 3.12.1
  _________________________
[| +   | |   Batteries   - |
 |_____|_|_________________|
  _________________________
 | -  Type '#help;;' | | + |]
 |___________________|_|___|


Loading syntax extensions...
    Camlp4 Parsing version 3.12.1

# (* i am just a comment. nobody cares about me. oh wait! *);;
# Error: Parse error: illegal begin of top_phrase
#
```

I am getting this error

```
Error: Parse error: illegal begin of top_phrase
```

when I am try to enter a comment in the interpreter. Are comments not allowed in ocaml interpreter or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: guess this is because `;;` is outside comment

Comment: If the `;;` was inside the comment block, the interpreter would expect input until terminated again with `;;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say you're entering nothing at all, which is a syntax error.

```
# (* Hello *) ;;
Error: Syntax error
```

Try entering something after the comment:

```
# (* Hello *) 3 ;;
- : int = 3
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Even python and ruby didn't allow comments like this in their REPLs.  Only Erlang and mono-csharp-shell allowed this. So I guess it is fair to not expect something like this.